# Page format using CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to align all the text in this page to the right of the picture, and then put some kind of a box around the whole thing to have the content aligned in the  center of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Test page</title>
 <style>

 body {
 padding-top: 10px;
 }

 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

 <div>
  <h1>The Title</h1>
 </div>

 <hr>

 <div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  </div>

 <div>
  <h3>Brief Description</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra
euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae. Sed dui lorem,
adipiscing in adipiscing et, interdum nec metus. Mauris ultricies,
justo eu convallis placerat, felis enim.
  </p>

  <h3>More Details</h3>
  <ul>
   <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
   <li>Dolor Sit Amet</li>
   <li>Consectetur</li>
   <li>Adipiscing Elit</li>
 </ul>

 </div>

 </div>

<hr>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably won't get much help unless you at least give it try first.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test page</title>
  <style>
    body {
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <h1>The Title</h1>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
      <div Style="float: left; width: 30%">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
      </div>
      <div Style="float: left; width: 70%">
        <h3>Brief Description</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra
        euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae. Sed dui lorem,
        adipiscing in adipiscing et, interdum nec metus. Mauris ultricies,
        justo eu convallis placerat, felis enim.
       </p>
       <h3>More Details</h3>
       <ul>
         <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
         <li>Dolor Sit Amet</li>
         <li>Consectetur</li>
         <li>Adipiscing Elit</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great starting for me, I need to add to empty rows on each side of the page to make eveything center.

Comment: Just having problems with the <hr> tags, its wrapping around the page if I change the width to 20% and 70%, why it happens?

Comment: Because 20% and 70% does not cover the whole width of the page. That causes the <hr> jumps at the empty space

Comment: Hi, @Maresia if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.